# Ajax response in alert

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a test.php file as:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $json_array = array();
    $json_array['success']='1';
    echo json_encode($json_array);
?>
```

On an input button click response needed in an alert.

```
 <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="AJAX Request" />
```

Comment: show your ajax @Amit Kaushal

Comment: use `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`